# EventListener for List changes in Sharepoint Hosted app

Tags: javascript, csom, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-addin

I'm developing a sharepoint hosted Add-in, which should react to a change of a list field of a list in the hostweb. I need some kind of EventListener for a list field.

For example:

List field Gets updated --> DOM object in Add-in should react (not in realtime, but <2-3 seconds would be nice)

Is there any kind of service for this in sharepoint? Or does anyohne have an idea, how this could be solved?

I have no idea how to realize that with the CSOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are called "Remote Event Receivers" and they are only available in Provider Hosted Add-Ins (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx.)

Given that SP Hosted Add-Ins can only use javascript that executes in the browser, there is no way to react to an OOTB event such as `ItemUpdated`.

What you could do is implement a custom form within your add-in that is able to update the appropriate list items in your host web, as well as perform whatever logic is needed while updating those items.

If you want a page or app-part in your add-in to respond to a change in the host web *while the page or app part is open in a browser*, you could do something like poll the hostweb every few seconds, checking for the change. You may be able to use `GetListItemChangesSinceToken` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292554.aspx, or just a simple query to the list. Be careful of querying too often for performance reasons, especially if the target list in the host web is large (>5000 items.)

Comment: That sounds good. Thanks for your answer! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As Sean mentioned to use a simple query to the list and since `getListItemChangesSinceToken()` [did not work for me](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169693/correct-usage-of-getlistitemchangessincetoken-in-javascript), I came up with the following:

- query the list with `window.setInterval(myFunctionThatTriggersTheQuery(), 10000)`
- The `myFunctionThatTriggersTheQuery()` function also saves the current time into a variable. I'm using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) with this function: `moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")`, this format can be used in a query and Sharepoint compares the values of the desired list field (in my case the 'Modified' field of the list) and the value of the variable
- Change the CSS on the page in the `successHandler` method of `executeQueryAsync` by iterating through the returned collection

and the following query:

```
    "<View>" +
        "<ViewFields>" +
          "<FieldRef Name='Modified' />" +
        "</ViewFields>" +
      "<Query>" +
        "<Where>" +
          "<Gt>" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Modified'/>" +
              "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'>" + myTimeVariable + "</Value>" +
          "</Gt>" +
        "</Where>" +
      "</Query>" +
    "</View>";
```

It is important to use the `IncludeTimeValue='True'` attribute if you want the know the change in between seconds/minutes/hours.

I tried this in a List with about 300 items and there where no noticeable perfomance issues.
I hope this can help someone :)