# Correct usage of getListItemChangesSinceToken() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsom, synchronisation

I'm working on a Sharepoint hosted App, that accesses List Data from the Hostweb as I outlined here: [EventListener for List changes in Sharepoint Hosted app](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168306/eventlistener-for-list-changes-in-sharepoint-hosted-app)

I want to use the `GetListItemChangesSinceToken` method as mentioned by Sean in the answer of the question I linked above.

Now, it seems that I get the first request working and the raw answer to the `POST` looks quite good (sending a token as `null` value gives me a fresh token and a lot of list data).

But somehow the `executeQueryAsync()` method always calls the `errorHandler` method and returns this error message: `Unexpected response from server.` Even though the `POST` answer looks fine.

So here is my code so far:

```
    // get all the needed contexts and web for accessing the hostweb 
    // (this part is definitely working)
    var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));    
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostweburl);
    var web = hostContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("My List Title");

    // create Query
    var cliQuery = new SP.ChangeLogItemQuery();
    cliQuery.set_changeToken(null);

    // apply getListItemChangesSinceToken to list and execute query
    list.getListItemChangesSinceToken(cliQuery);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler);
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Ben

Comment: If the idea is to get the last changes in the list, then it could be easier to return items with a modified date greater than X. I did some tests in the past with `GetListItemChangesSinceToken` and it was difficult to use....

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I agree with the difficulty of `GetListItemChangesSinceToken`. I threw that away. The solution I'm using now is a query, that returns all List Items where the Modified field time value is bigger than the time of the last query with an interval of queries.